# Steam takes forever to load, a week downloading a game, and keeps pausing

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I have done everything and nothing works. It takes Steam forever to start up with updating and verifying. When it does come up, it takes a week to install a game, and keeps pausing.
I have run a speed test and get 128 Mbps download and 29.5 upload. I've never had problems, but it started the last 2 weeks.

I've completely uninstalled Steam and had to reinstall games. Didn't work. So I kept my steam.exe, Steam apps, and user data folder and reinstalled Steam , closed out everything, all programs, antivirus, and still keep getting the same problems. So I gave up on Steam and tried to play games on Uplay, but run into the same problem.
What can I do?

Comment: Firewall issues? Is your ISP blocking certain addresses? I think contacting them might prove insightful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's your download and not your installation? You'll notice that a Steam download has two activities: network activity and disk activity. Sometimes, if your disk is slow or otherwise full, it can take forever to "download" something, but in reality everything's already downloaded, it just needs to be installed.

Comment: Disk is full? (or not enough room to unpack and your disk is cache thrashing or w/e it's called) +1

Comment: my bad yes when I install it keeps pausing. I have 394GB space available. It finally installed my games from Sunday.